# PHP Script causeing HTTP Error 500

Tags: http

So I have this working on my local testing machine and it works fine. However as soon as I upload it to my hosting provider it gives me an HTTP error 500 and wont go any further. The part of the script that is giving trouble is:

```
function collect_directories_and_files($path) {
$entries = scandir($path);
return array_partition($entries, function($entry) {
    return is_dir($entry);
});
}
```

More specifically:

```
 return array_partition($entries, function($entry) {
```

This is the line that the error logs are calling out as the problem. I dont see any syntax errors...am I missing something?

EDIT: Apparently this is an issue with PHP 5.2 and annonymous functions.

Comment: _"This is the line that the error logs are calling out as the problem. I dont see any syntax errors...am I missing something?"_ - yeah, and we too, required to answer this question: what is the error?

Comment: It was an HTTP error 500 but when I got to digging it was a T_FUNCTION error and with some research it has something to do with PHP 5.2 and annonymous function or so I think. Maybee someone will have a better answer.

Comment: The **exact** error might help, but if I must guess, you may not call your function `function`. Try renaming it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you have enough permission to list the files/directories on the path.

It's working because maybe you have permissions on your local host but you don't on the remote.

Comment: Permissions for the folder and the file are set to 755 im not sure Im tracking your meaning on "permissions" they are set the same on both setups.